# Date equal to or smaller than x in VB

Tags: ms-access, vba, if-statement

I would have thought `Form!MyForm!Date >= #1/12/2010#` would have done the trick but it doesnt seem to be working.

Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong

Full Code:

```
If (Forms!MyForm!DateSubmitted >= #1/01/2012#) Then
MsgBox ("Past due date")
End If
```

Comment: Is `DateSubmitted` a textbox? If yes then you are comparing a string to a date. You will have to convert `Forms!MyForm!DateSubmitted` to a date first before you can compare.

Comment: I would also like to add that the date that you have in `DateSubmitted` has to represent a valid string date for example "1/1/2012" and not "1.1.2012"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CDate function to, at least, make sure you are comparing two dates:

```
If (CDate(Forms!MyForm!DateSubmitted) >= #1/1/2012#) Then
    MsgBox ("Past due date")
End If
```

If your input string is not a valid date string, you will get Type error but you will know that you are not comparing date type to date.

Plus, check the valid date you compare to:

```
Form!MyForm!Date >= #1/12/2010# '2010
```

vs.

```
Forms!MyForm!DateSubmitted >= #1/01/2012# '2012
```